# Making Dreamweaver more like Notepad++

Tags: customization, dreamweaver, notepad++, hotkeys

I'm moving to Dreamweaver from Notepad++, and while Dw does have many better features than Notepad++, there are a few that I'm really missing.

1. Is there a way to make the "Home" key on the keyboard take you to the front of where the code starts, instead of the very front of the line? In Notepad++ this is how it works by default, and I don't know why anyone would want to go to the very front of the line instead of the front of the code. I use tabbing to keep it more organized, so this feature is really important to me.
2. How do I duplicate a line in Dw? In Notepad++ I can select the line and press ctrl + d and it automatically duplicated the code. This is awesome for something like a gallery or a table where I don't want to have to type out every line because it's so similar.
3. Less important, as I don't use this that often, but can you vertically select in Dw? In Notepad++ you can hold down alt and select lines vertically. Ex:

   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12147973/vert-select.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: #1 and #3 are probably answered with "No". Then again, I haven't used Dreamweaver for years.

Comment: damn, #1's the most important to me :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For #2, check out the [Code Extras extension for Dreamweaver](http://xtnd.us/dreamweaver/codeextras)

No Longer works in DW5.5; Try here - http://yoropan.com/en/archives/544

Comment: Thanks, that's the best answer I've had so far.

Comment: CS6 refuses to import these plugins, just a heads up. Doesn't seem to be a replacement yet.

Comment: There is no any hints what to do with the file they offer. Just "Download `CodeExtras.mxp` and use". But how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

I was also wanting some of this features... I discovered that, at least in CS6, #2 is already in Dreamweaver, but the shortcut is Ctrl+Alt+Down ou Up, depending on the direction that you wanna duplicate the code.

Note that I had to disable the shortcut that turns your screen view for that to work. (It's an intel default, press Ctrl+Alt+f12 to open the options)

And tãa dãaa... IT WORKS! :D

Comment: Interesting. I just tried this in Dreamweaver CC, and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I never used CC, but check Commands -> CodeEditUtils and see if there's nothing related there.

Answer (score 1):

I want to say one thing different. My Dreamweaver theme (Users who use Dreamweaver after use Notepad++). Download [Dreamweaver.xml](https://hotfile.com/dl/199056455/b4d5264/Dreamweaver.xml.html)

"Dreamweaver.xml" file is in here for windows: C:\Program Files\Notepad++\themes\Dreamweaver.xml

Comment: Thank you for sharing this file. I was thinking about making it myself, but never did it. I'm just lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to #1 = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> in anything in windows will take you to the absolute start of the documents, same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> to start and finish of lines, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> arrow to jump entire words...

I too am on the quest for duplicating lines in DW.  #3 your image no longer shows.

Comment: No, that is NOT the answer to #1. Your answer takes you to the start of the document. His desire is to jump to the first actual character of code in the line his cursor is, skipping all the whitespace used for indenting. DW jumps you to the first position of line, before all the whitespace, then we have to hit `Ctrl+<RightArrow>` to get to the first word in that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to duplicated a line I click on the line number, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.  Is that what you're looking for or am I being simple?

Comment: Sorry, this is what users try to avoid, more typing/movements than needed. Most IDEs I have used allow line duplication such as `Ctrl+D`, plus this does NOT use the clipboard, meaning you can still `Ctrl+V` some other code you are hanging onto. Less work means more productive. `Click in gutter` + `Ctrl+C` + `Ctrl+V` + `Ctrl+V` is not as fast as `Ctrl+D`. Dreamweaver is stuck in the past because they were the best 20 years ago and they don't care about catching up with the rest of the world...

Comment: Given that Dreamweaver does not support CTRL & D I think my answer works.  It may be the case that they are not the best, or are stuck in the past, I'm certainly not it's biggest fan, but it's what the user (and myself) uses, so it's the solution we're stuck with.

Comment: I am pretty sure your method is how the OP is doing things now and was looking for an alternative, similar to how almost any other IDE or text editor like NPP does things. I absolutely agree that your method works. An answer to the question could be "There is no alternative" where giving him exactly what he is doing now and what he is trying to avoid would cause him to ask the same question again "How do I avoid having to copy/paste the line?"